# Display Git log including Notes in online

Tags: git, logging

I need to sort out some commits based on its notes.
Is there anyway to display git logs in single line including notes coming with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log --format='%h %N'`

This will show short commit hash and commit notes. `%h` is for short commit hash and `%N` is for notes. You can format the output in any way you want. For example, you can format the output as CSV for easy parsing using this:

`git log --format='"%h","%N"'`

It is possible to show many other information like subject line, author, committer, date etc. All valid options can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats).